В-дерево на C#. Неправильный вывод в графвиз
Реализовал В-дерево на C#, но есть проблема: при добавлении нового значения в дерево в визуализации оно записывается третьим в узел. Уже много раз пересматривал код, но не могу найти, в чём ошибка. Прилагаю вывод из графвиза и выходной код программы формата .dot
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
 
public class BTreeNode
{
    public List<int> keys;
    public List<BTreeNode> children;
    public bool isLeaf;
    public int n;
 
    public BTreeNode(int n, bool isLeaf)
    {
        this.n = n;
        this.isLeaf = isLeaf;
        keys = new List<int>();
        children = new List<BTreeNode>();
    }
}
 
public class BTree
{
    public BTreeNode root;
    public int t;
 
    public BTree(int t)
    {
        this.t = t;
        root = new BTreeNode(t, true);
    }
 
    public void Insert(int key)
    {
        BTreeNode r = root;
        if (r.keys.Count == 2 * t - 1)
        {
            BTreeNode s = new BTreeNode(t, false);
            s.children.Add(r);
            SplitChild(s, 0, r);
            root = s;
            InsertNonFull(s, key);
        }
        else
        {
            InsertNonFull(r, key);
        }
    }
 
    private void InsertNonFull(BTreeNode x, int key)
    {
        int i = x.keys.Count - 1;
        if (x.isLeaf)
        {
            x.keys.Add(0);
            while (i >= 0 && key < x.keys[i])
            {
                x.keys[i + 1] = x.keys[i];
                i--;
            }
            x.keys[i + 1] = key;
        }
        else
        {
            while (i >= 0 && key < x.keys[i])
            {
                i--;
            }
            i++;
            if (x.children[i].keys.Count == 2 * t - 1)
            {
                SplitChild(x, i, x.children[i]);
                if (key > x.keys[i])
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            InsertNonFull(x.children[i], key);
        }
    }
 
    private void SplitChild(BTreeNode x, int i, BTreeNode y)
    {
        BTreeNode z = new BTreeNode(t, y.isLeaf);
        x.children.Insert(i + 1, z);
        x.keys.Insert(i, y.keys[t - 1]);
        z.keys.AddRange(y.keys.GetRange(t, t - 1));
        y.keys.RemoveRange(t - 1, t);
        if (!y.isLeaf)
        {
            z.children.AddRange(y.children.GetRange(t, t));
            y.children.RemoveRange(t, t);
        }
    }
 
    public void PrintDotFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("digraph BTree {");
            PrintDotNode(root, sw);
            sw.WriteLine("}");
        }
    }
 
    private void PrintDotNode(BTreeNode node, StreamWriter sw)
    {
        string label = string.Join(",", node.keys);
        sw.WriteLine($"node{node.GetHashCode()} [shape=box, label=\"{label}\"];");
        if (!node.isLeaf)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < node.children.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine($"node{node.GetHashCode()} -> node{node.children[i].GetHashCode()};");
                PrintDotNode(node.children[i], sw);
            }
        }
    }
}
 
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BTree bTree = new BTree(2); // Создаем B-дерево с t=2
        bTree.Insert(1);
        bTree.Insert(2);
        bTree.Insert(3);
        bTree.Insert(4);
        bTree.Insert(5);
        bTree.Insert(6);
        bTree.Insert(7);
        bTree.Insert(8);
        bTree.Insert(9);
        bTree.Insert(10);
        bTree.Insert(11);
 
 
        bTree.PrintDotFile("btree.dot"); // Выводим результат в файл btree.dot
    }
}

